# Bootstrap: 1 column out of 3 isn't aligning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, multiple-columns

I am having problems making a column inside a row align with the others ones:

I have 1 row with 3 columns, but the third column is lower than the other 2.
The 1st column has an image, the 2nd text, and the 3rd another image.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="video" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
  <img src="img/flowers.png">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 text pull-center">
  <h1>SEE HOW IT WORKS</h1> 
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
  <img src="img/root.png">
  </div>

  </div>
<!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 2):

`pull-right` and `Pull-center` are wrongly used here.

You do not need these values to just tile stuff in Bootstrap

These settings will make a div `float` not actually putting them in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to set the `pull-x` class :

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/TP8WbICyat)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="video" class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src="img/flowers.png">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 text">
  <h1>SEE HOW IT WORKS</h1> 
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src="img/root.png">
  </div>

  </div></div>

<div id="push"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with img-responsive and is missing close the div at the end ---

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="video" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="img/flowers.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 text">
      <h1>SEE HOW IT WORKS</h1> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="img/root.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```